# Spurious punctuation in xelatex + biblatex + Cyrillic or Greek

Tags: biblatex, xetex, punctuation

`Biblatex` has a mechanism that prevents spurious punctuation. Generally, it works fine but fails with `xetex` and some languages. The MWE below compiles fine with pdflatex but with xelatex yields double points after capital (!) letters in Greek and Russian. What could be the problem?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@PUNCT{pat1,
  location = {W.},
  publisher = {U.},
  usere={w.},
  userf={u.},
  language = {english},
  hyphenation = {english},
}
@PUNCT{pat2,
  location = {Ψ.},
  publisher = {Ω.},
  usere={ψ.},
  userf={ω.},
  language = {greek},
  hyphenation = {greek},
}
@PUNCT{pat3,
  location = {Ш.},
  publisher = {Ж.},
  usere={ш.},
  userf={ж.},
  language = {russian},
  hyphenation = {russian},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
%------------ XeTeX -------------------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english,russian}
\else
%------------ pdftex ---------------------------------
\usepackage[T1,T2A,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[english,russian,greek]{babel}
\fi
\usepackage[autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{punct}{%
  \printfield{usere}\addperiod
  \printfield{userf}\addperiod
  \printlist{location}\addperiod
  \printlist{publisher}\finentry}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: xelatex punctuation]

Comment: There has just been added a bug report about this at the [`biblatex` bug tracker: #368](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/368)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed in the current DEV versions of biblatex 3.4 and biber 2.5. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/368 .