# XeLaTeX + polyglossia + Russian or Greek = page number in italics

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, amsthm, italic, cyrillic

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

    \itshape Text.

\end{document}
```

Compiling with XeLaTeX, surprisingly, you get in italics not only *Text*, but also the page number *1*. The same for `\setdefaultlanguage{greek}`, but with `\setdefaultlanguage{english}` everything is ok (just like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230616/spurious-punctuation-in-xelatex-biblatex-cyrillic-or-greek)).

I know how to fix it, just use braces: `{ \itshape Text. }`.

Now consider the following related example with `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

    Text.

    \vspace{52em}

    Text.

    \begin{theorem}
        Text.
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Again you get the page number in italics:
[image: page number in italics]
Why is there such a problem and is there any workaround?

Comment: If I may add some details: **It only happens** if the text ends just before the page ends forcing the "theorem" line to the second page. However, **it doesn't happen** if you use `\newpage`/ `\pagebreak` or if the text from the first goes a bit on the second page.

Comment: Imho it is a polyglossia bug, `\normalfont` doesn't work correctly as you can see with `Text    \itshape  Text. \normalfont Text
 \normalfontlatin Text`. `\usepackage[russian]{babel}\usepackage{fontspec}` works better.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the `\normalfont` addition! I agree it's probably a polyglossia bug, but for Russian and other non-Latin languages polyglossia is still a better choice than babel. @Alenanno yeah, forgot to mention that; and thanks, `\newpage` / `\pagebreak` actually works as a manual workaround :)

Comment: The russian.ldf of babel has been adapted to lualatex/xelatex, so it is imho worth a try. But if you want to stay with polyglossia you should redefine the header/footers e.g. with fancyhdr to force upright font shape (and other font features, bold would have the same problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then `\normalfont` which  doesn't work correctly as @Ulrike said  you can use `\upshape` to change font shape for page numbering

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\renewcommand{\thepage}{\upshape\arabic{page}}



\begin{document}

    Text.

    \vspace{52em}

    Text.

    \begin{theorem}
        Text.
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder of that problem! :) I had already solved it, but forgot to write the soluton here. My solution is essentially the same as yours but using a nice package `fancyhdr`. The code is: `\usepackage{fancyhdr} \fancypagestyle{plain}{ \fancyhf{} \fancyfoot[C]{\textup{\thepage}} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} } \pagestyle{plain}`