# Headers in my article have italic instead of normal font, when there is a \newpage inside a theorem enviroment

Tags: xetex, header-footer, fancyhdr, polyglossia, italic

Like you suggest, i fix the minimum working example. When i use the package **polyglossia**, the Headers/Footers are in *Italic* for the page that contains the first half theorem.

```
\documentclass{article}%%% OR dependencies


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{polyglossia}       
\setmainlanguage[variant=mono]{greek}   
\setotherlanguage{english}    
\setmainfont{Arial}    

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{amssymb} % maths
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Λήμμα}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Ορισμός}[section]
\newtheorem{claim}{Ισχυρισμός}[section]
\newtheorem{guess}{Εικασία}[section]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont HEAD}
\fancyfoot[R]{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont PAGE}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont FOOT}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\newpage
\begin{guess}
\label{first_claim}
Text first Page $k+1$,\newpage test second page.
\end{guess} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HenriMenke thank you for show me how to locate my problem.

Comment: You need to post compilable code,  so our computer can reproduce your outut.  Just by looking at one line,  we cannot  fix the cause.

Comment: Please tell us how the `guess` environment is defined, and do please tell us which package you load to define theorem-like environments. Which LaTeX format do you employ? Which text fonts do you employ? Aside: Why is there a page break inside the `guess` environment? How long do these guesses tend to be? Basically, please provide all information needed to generate the issue you need to fix.

Comment: i used `asmthm` for `guess` environment - header and footer are not in italic check it.

Comment: @Mu30murugans2katgmail i can't locate the asmthm, and i already using a cls, sto asmart (asmcls) is no a option.

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: The problem wasn't in the theorem. is at the use of theorem and the polyglossia package

Comment: Your code does not compile. You need to fix the compilation errors first. While you have errors, the output is irrelevant.

Comment: You should not be loading `babel` *and* `polyglossia` and you should not load `inputenc` if using Lua/XeTeX.

Comment: @cfr i am using xelatex. to tell you the truth, i have added many packages, without know the meaning and the use of them. My code compiles, but it generates many warnings, no errors. I found my solution. Thank you for you time. First time in latex

Comment: Adding packages blind is a recipe for trouble. Use either Babel or Polyglossia, but not both. Don't use `inputenc` with XeTeX or LuaTeX. Don't load packages you don't need, especially if you don't know what they do.

Answer (score 0):

After the help on the comments, i locate the problem. There was already another question with a working answear [XeLaTeX + polyglossia + Russian or Greek = page number in italics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281092/xelatex-polyglossia-russian-or-greek-page-number-in-italics).